# Why does my project always try to download the latest spring-beans 3.2.*.RELEASE artefact

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-bean

I have a spring MVC web application that has the following spring dependencies:

```
spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-context-support-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-jms-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-orm-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-test-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-tx-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE

spring-spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE
spring-security-web-3.2.0.RELEASE
spring-security-config-3.2.0.RELEASE
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.0.RELEASE
```

My question is that when i build using mvn clean install does it try and download spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE. I am assuming one of my dependencies is dragging it in but not sure which.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is version 3.2.10.RELEASE? I can`t find this version in [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans)?

Comment: This is the error in my log when I run in debug:
[DEBUG] Intercepted artifact downloading event: ARTIFACT_DOWNLOADING org.springframework:spring-beans:pom:3.2.10.RELEASE @ central (http://maven.*******.co.uk:8081/artifactory/libs-release, releases)

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose ` to find out where the dependency comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your dependencies in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of POM. The versions that you define in `<dependencyManagement>` will apply not only to the dependencies that you mention in the top-level `<dependencies>` section, but also to their transitive dependencies.

For example:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

These fragments will make sure that Maven uses only version `3.2.1.RELEASE`. (Note that there are no `<version>` in the second section.)

If you still want to find out where that dependency comes from, and if you use Eclipse, open your `pom.xml` and have a look at the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab. If necessary, you can double-click on dependencies there: it will open the dependency's own `pom.xml` where you can research transitive dependencies further.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your proble in the following way:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

and then you can manage your dependency without worry of single version number. In this way all spring dependencies will have the same 4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version